# SSRS set last row as default value for multi-value parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I guess that's easy... I have a multi-value parameter that got the list of values from a query. I would like to select as default value the last row.

Can I achieve this using a expression? I would like to avoid creating a second query just to get the last value from the previous query...

Comment: Frame the `order by ` clause in your query to retrieve the last row for the `parameter` dataset .Such as order by `column desc`

Comment: Sorry, which expression I should write?

Comment: Can you show us the query which is being used by the `parameter` ?

Comment: The query is an MDX one that depending depending on several measures shows some months or not. The resulting list of months is dynamic. I could replicate the query adding a second dataset just to get the default values just getting the last value on the first query but it seems unelegant. I thought it was easy to just select the first item  or the last item using expressions in the Default values screen but I'm not able to figure out how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the default parameter expression you **can't refer to the field of the dataset**, so you can't write something like `Last(Field!MyVar.Value, "DataSet1")`, as a workaround you can order your dataset to retrive last row as first and use "Get values from a query" which choses first row, if you can't do this then replicate your dataset in the only one solution.

Comment: I thought I would be be able to use =Parameters!MyMultiValueParam.Value(0) or DataSet. Don't understand why it cannot be done. At the end I replicated the same MDX query with Tail on Rows axis...

Comment: DataSet is only metadata (query, query parameters, filters, and a field collection), you can't refer to fields by index because at run-time, the report processor retrieves the actual data and combines it with the report layout. DataSet is actually internal object...

Comment: @RomanBadiornyi - You say that the "Get values from query" option "chooses the first row".  I have a multi-select dropdown populated by a parameter that uses this option, and when I preview my report I see all the values selected by default, not just the first one.  This is SSRS 2012, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with **SSRS 2012** and I was using a multi select option on my report so when I chose the "Get Values from a query" I got all of the values as the default.

I did find a solution. In my report I needed the default name of the town to be the first one so I created another set with the name of the column and a calculated measure that said "`[DimTahanot].[Tahana Name].&[אילת]`" and filtered it by the same one. (Please ignore the different language). Although hard coded it was good for this report. You could create another hidden parameter for this set if you need it to be the first one by amount or any other parameters that should effect this value, using the filter as a parameter.

Hope this helps.